# Redux/React state normalization - why maintain a separate array of IDs?

Tags: react-redux, normalization

Following the tutorial by Dan Abramov here: https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-normalizing-the-state-shape

He doesn't seem to explain the benefit of maintaining an extra reducer with an array of todo IDs (allIds), would it not be easier to have just the one byId reducer and user Object.keys or Object.values to iterate over it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample Todo app shows a list of todos, in the order in which they were created. It's not possible to retrieve that ordered list in a way that is guaranteed to work across browsers using an `Object` and `Object.keys`.

JS `Object` properties are unordered, but arrays have an order. So the ordering of the output of `Object.keys()` is not guaranteed to have any relationship to the order in which the keys were added. The array allows the reducer to display the todos in the order in which they were added.

Theoretically [you could use a `Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), as the keys in a `Map` are ordered. However, there's no way to re-order the contents of a `Map`. With an array you could re-order the IDs without needing to touch the todo objects themselves.

In other words, the array data structure is better suited to storing ordered lists than both `Object` and `Map`.

Comment: Very confused by the downvote. Pretty sure this answer is correct.